# Return the index of the element within the list in c#

Tags: list, loops, razor

I have the following code which iterates through a list of the signed in users predictions for a series of football matches:

```
@foreach (var scorecast in Model.Prediction.Scorecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    @*<td><input id="fixtureid" name="fixtureid" type="text" value="@scorecast.Fixture.FixtureID" /></td>*@
                    <td align="center"><img src="@scorecast.Fixture.HomeTeam.Thumb" style="max-height:30px;max-width:30px;" /></td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">@scorecast.Fixture.HomeTeam.Name</td>
                    <td align="center"><img src="@scorecast.Fixture.AwayTeam.Thumb" style="max-height:30px;max-width:30px;" /></td>
                    <td class="hidden-xs">@scorecast.Fixture.AwayTeam.Name</td>
                    <td>@scorecast.HomeGoals - @scorecast.AwayGoals</td>
                    <td>@Model.AdminPrediction.Scorecasts.ToList()[x].HomeGoals - @Model.AdminPrediction.Scorecasts.ToList()[x].AwayGoals </td>
                    <td>@Model.GuestPrediction.Scorecasts.ToList()[x].HomeGoals - @Model.GuestPrediction.Scorecasts.ToList()[x].AwayGoals</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

As you will see from the last two  in the row I am attempting to call the predictions of an admin and a guest to compare with the users but I am unsure as to how I can set an iterator x using the list of scorecasts for the user

Answer (score 0):

There should be several ways you can set an iterator.

1. If your Model.AdminPrediction, Model.GuestPrediction, Model.Prediction are all the same length you could use a for(var x = 0; x < Model.Prediction.Scorecast.length;x++) instead of the foreach loop
2. If they are all different AdminPrediction and GuestPrediction are the same and Prediction is not (as i am assuming from your code), you might want to think about adding a common idnetifier. I am guessing this might be a prediction for a game, so you could use the game.id. For example you would use:

@Model.GuestPrediction.Scorecars.ToList().Select(x => x.game.id == scorecast.game.id).First()
@Model.AdminPrediction.Scorecars.ToList().Select(x => x.game.id == scorecast.game.id).First()

1. If you dont have either of those, you will need to iterate through the adminPrediction list until you find what you are looking for, save the index of that item and use that as you x in the guestPrediction.

Let me know if none of these works.